# Does the stack also follow the little-endian convention in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning Assembly (x86 NASM) at university. Needless to say, I am extremely confused and don't understand much. We've recently learned about little-endian, so we're right at the beginning.

During the lecture, our professor said that we have to be careful when working with the stack, we have to keep little-endian in mind. I don't really understand why this is. My question is: Does the stack also follow the little endian convention? I tried to see this in the Debugger and by what I saw, I think that the stack doesn't actually follow the little-endian convention, which to me doesn't make sense, I expected the stack to be in little-endian also, just like the Hex Dump. I hope the following example can illustrate what I mean:

1. Let's say that I push into the register `EAX` the value of `12345678h`. It gets stored in the same way as I wrote it, i.e., it gets stored as `12345678`. So it is **not** stored using the little-endian convention. No surprise here, I expected this.

[image]

2. Here is my confusion. Now, I pushed the value in the register `EAX` onto the stack. I totally expected it to be stored using the little-endian convention. So I expected it to be stored in the stack as `78563412`, but to my surprise, it's not stored like that. It's stored just the way it is stored in the register `EAX`, so I am led to believe that the stack doesn't follow the little-endian convention.

[image]

3. Just to regain a little bit of my sanity, I also moved the value of the register `EAX` into a `dword` variable called `a`. This was indeed stored in little endian. No surprise here either, I totally expected this.

[image]

So you see, my problem is at point (2) from the above. Why is the value of the register not stored in the stack using the little-endian convention? That is what I actually expected. Can I conclude that the stack does **not** follow the little-endian convention? If so, then what did my professor mean when he said we need to keep little-endian in mind when working with the stack?

Comment: The right side stack dump already undoes the little endian for you to be more human readable. It's a feature of your debugger. If you look at the byte dump just as you did for the data section, it will be little endian all right.

Comment: Go to memory location 19FF70 and check, it'll be in little endian.

Comment: @Jester Oooooh, I see. That makes sense, I just didn't know that the stack undoes the little endian automatically. Thank you so much!

Comment: @tkausl Yep, I got it now. Thanks a lot!